# PHP - Get the keys of values which are congruent in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which potentially is able to carry multiple congruent values.

```
$a = array( "0" => "red", "1" => "green" , "2" => "red" , "3" => "blue", "4" => "blue", "5" => "blue" );
```

Now, I need to know the keys of all elements which have at least one congruent value.

My prefered result would be an array which has subarrays- and in each subarray the keys of the different congruent values get stored. So that I know which one of the keys of **array $a** have the same value.

```
$b = array(array("0" => "0", "1" => "2"), array("0" => "3", "1" => "4", "2" => "5"));
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean with "at least one congruent value"  .. ??? .. show us your expected  result

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer Output is not making sense. Explain it please.

Comment: a good explanation  for the expected result is required

Comment: I´m sorry guys, I´m trying. I feel abit stupid know :)

Comment: Sorry to say but this is still unclear. What does the first subarray `array("0" => "0", "1" => "2")` mean?

Comment: The first subarray contains the keys of **red** from the array **$a**

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer Ahh got it now. Added my answer.

Comment: I shouldn´t have done it with numberkeys, with keywords it would be much easier to understand i think

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer My current result in the answer also gives you keys for better understanding. See that demo link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get the frequency count for each color. Then iterate over the array `$a` and check each color's frequency count. If it's greater than `1`, add it to the result at the appropriate color index in `$keys`.

```
<?php

$a = array( "0" => "red", "1" => "green" , "2" => "red" , "3" => "blue", "4" => "blue", "5" => "blue" );

$group_by_data = array_count_values($a);

$keys = [];

foreach($a as $key => $color){
    if($group_by_data[$color] > 1){
        if(!isset($keys[$color])) $keys[$color] = [];
        $keys[$color][] = $key;
    }    
}


print_r($keys);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/mI02u

Comment: thank you. Now, I would need this function for a search and I want to make it as fast as possible. I´m not that experienced, so here is another question: I have the same values in my MySQL Database. Would it be faster to make a mysqlquery to get the wanted data?

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer Not sure what you mean by search but in most of the cases, getting the result from mysql query would be faster than PHP search, because of avoid double processing of the same data and using MySQL features which involves indexing of data etc. I would suggest you to add this as a new question in follow up to this one.

Comment: Maybe your curious. I did a speedtest: Your solution took 0.0036790370941162 seconds and @Atal Prateeks took 0.024911165237427 seconds to process the same data. Which is a ttremendous difference in my eyes.

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer Yes, mine is a bit more efficient. Time difference could increase I presume if tested on arrays of size 10000 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_unique` to find all unique values then loop through it and use `array_keys` to find all the keys of each element.

```
$a = array( "0" => "red", "1" => "green" , "2" => "red" , "3" => "blue", "4" => "blue", "5" => "blue" );
$unique=array_unique($a);
$result=array();
foreach($unique as $value){
    $allkeys=array_keys($a, $value);
    if(count($allkeys)>1)
        $result[]=$allkeys;
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to have a play with performance, I tried using a (sort of) combination of the two approaches.  First count the values, then loop over this and use `array_keys()` to get the entries with these colors...

```
$a = array( "0" => "red", "1" => "green" , "2" => "red" , "3" => "blue", "4" => "blue", "5" => "blue" );

$group_by_data = array_count_values($a);

$keys = [];

foreach ( $group_by_data as $key => $value )    {
    if ( $value > 1 )   {
        $keys[$key] = array_keys($a, $key);
    }
}

print_r($keys);
```